Where do installed programs go?
When I install a program via command line, where does it go?
And how do I get an icon on the desktop?
I managed (I think) to  install a couple of programs but don't know where they are. One place I looked said /usr/local, but I can't find that either. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

When you install packages in Ubuntu, where the get installed on your system varies on what type of package you installed, and for many (esp. deb) where the packager of that package intended for the package to install. Our systems are built from many packages from many teams (GNU, Linux, GNOME, LXQt, LibreOffice etc) and they each can have their own standards; some packages in Ubuntu repositories flowing from upstream Debian too... For more maybe read https://ubuntu.com/about/packages etc, or what's in a package https://askubuntu.com/questions/483175/how-do-i-list-the-contents-of-a-package etc

Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/32507/158442

When you install a software from the official APT repositories, in most cases,

The binary executable goes to /usr/bin.
The icon goes to some place in /usr/share/icons
The desktop file (which creates menu launchers) goes to /usr/share/applications.
Documentations may go to /usr/share/doc.
Many proprietary apps save their binaries in /opt, and symlink that to /usr/bin

There are separate directories for manual pages. And depending on the complexity of the package, files may go to many other places.
For an installed package with the name pkgname, run the command dpkg -L pkgname to find out list of all files.
Here is an example.
$ dpkg -L foliate
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/foliate
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.desktop
/usr/share/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate
/usr/share/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.gresource
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/foliate
/usr/share/doc/foliate/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/foliate/copyright
/usr/share/glib-2.0
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.gschema.xml
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/foliate
/usr/share/locale
/usr/share/locale/ar
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/cs
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/de
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/el
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/es
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/eu
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/fa_IR
/usr/share/locale/fa_IR/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/fa_IR/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/he
/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/hi
/usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/hr
/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/id
/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/ie
/usr/share/locale/ie/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ie/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/it
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/ko
/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/nb
/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/nl
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/nn
/usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/oc
/usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/tr
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/uk
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.mo
/usr/share/metainfo
/usr/share/metainfo/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.metainfo.xml



And how do I get an icon on the desktop?

Copy the .desktop file from /usr/share/applications to your Desktop directory in the home folder.
